# How to get department name of a module in Laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, models

I am trying to get the department that a module is part of in laravel like:

This is my Faculty class:

```
    <?php
class Faculty extends Eloquent {
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'faculty';
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * Whitelisted model properties for mass assignment.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $primaryKey='facultyid';

    protected $fillable = array('facultyname', 'facultyshort');

    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Departments', 'facultyid');
    }
}
```

This is my Departments class

```
    <?php
class Departments extends Eloquent {
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'departments';

    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * Whitelisted model properties for mass assignment.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $primaryKey='departmentid';
    protected $foreignKey='facultyid';

    protected $fillable = array('departmentname', 'departmenthead', 'facultyid');

    public function modules()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Modules', 'departmentid');
    }
    public function faculty()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Faculty', 'facultyid');
    }
}
```

and finally this is my modules class:

```
<?php
class Modules extends Eloquent {
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'modules';
    protected $foreignKey='departmentid';
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * Whitelisted model properties for mass assignment.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $primaryKey='mid';

    protected $fillable = array('mfulltitle', 'mshorttitle', 'mcode', 
        'mcrn', 'mfieldofstudy', 'mcoordinator','mlevel', 
        'mcredits', 'melective', 'departmentid');

    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Departments', 'departmentid');
    }

    public function classes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Classes', 'moduleid')->orderBy('classid', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

I have tried doing something like this:

```
@foreach(Modules::where('melective', '=', 1)->get() as $mod)
        {{$mod->mshorttitle}} belongs to department: {{ $mod->department->departmentname }}
    @endforeach
```

But it does not work, does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

==============================

**SOLUTION**

After a bit of work i figured it out

in Department class  i added the following function:

```
public function name()
{
    return $this->departmentname;
}
```

and i changed the code to the following:

```
@foreach(Modules::where('melective', '=', 1)->get() as $mod)
    {{$mod->mshorttitle}} belongs to department: {{ $mod->department->name() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Glad you found your solution. Please use the *Answer Your Question* button to post your solution instead of editing your question. Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean to say Models instead of Modules?